# Django form submition Problem with Submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-5

Im encountering a problem with an html template that i created using bootstrap so my problem is that i have a javascript working dynamically to add rows to a django form with 4 specific fields but whenever i add a row the submit button stops submitting results and instead adds more product fields to fill and they are initialized to None

here is the code for my html template

```
{% block createlist %}

<form id="form-container" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="form-group" id="form-group">
            
            <div class="row mt-3">
                
                <h4 class="card-title md-2 m-2">List Name</h4>
                <div class="m-2">{{ listform.name}}</div> 
            </div>

            <div id="button_row" class="row mt-0 no-gutters"> <!-- Apply .row class here -->
                <div class="row">
                    <h2 class="col-md-2  md-2 m-2">Products</h2>
                    <div id="add-form" class="col-md-1 md-2 m-2"><button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary">+</button></div>
                </div>
                

                <div class="col-md-2 m-2">Product Name</div> 
                <div class="col-md-2 m-2">Quantity</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 m-2">Weight</div>
                <div class="col-md-2 m-2">Price</div>

            </div>
            {{ productformset.management_form }}
            {% for form in productformset %}
            <div id="form-row" class="row mt-0 no-gutters"> <!-- Apply .row class here -->
                <div class="col-md-2 m-2"><input type="text" name="{{ form.prefix }}-product_name" value=""></div> 
                <div class="col-md-2 m-2"><input type="text" name="{{ form.prefix }}-quantity" value="{{ form.quantity.value }}"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 m-2"><input type="text" name="{{ form.prefix }}-weight" value="{{ form.weight.value }}"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2 m-2"><input type="text" name="{{ form.prefix }}-price" value="{{ form.price.value }}"></div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            
          
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>  
</form>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        let addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form");
        let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS");
        let productFormRowToClone = document.querySelector("#form-row");
        let productFormsContainer = document.querySelector("#form-group");

        let formNum = productFormRowToClone.children.length - 2;
        addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm);

        function addForm(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            let newProductFormRow = productFormRowToClone.cloneNode(true); // Clone the specific row

            // Increment form number
             // Exclude the header row
            formNum++;
            
            // Update the form prefixes
            let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`, 'g');

            newProductFormRow.innerHTML = newProductFormRow.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `form-${formNum}-`)

            // Insert the new form before the submit button
            productFormsContainer.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend",newProductFormRow);

            totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`);
        }
    });
</script>
{% endblock createlist %}
```

and here is a screenshot of the results when i click on the submit button the rows with none values were added when i clicked on submit button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZrU.png)

I tried changing so much in the javascript file but no chance i cannot find exactly what's causing the problem but before when the add button was not inside a div with class row it was under the whole container it worked fine

Comment: Where is the code for submitting the form? Even the function is called addForm, ao it only adds new fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your logic for counting the number of forms. To start with this is how your variable is initialized:

```
let formNum = productFormRowToClone.children.length - 2;
```

Here `productFormRowToClone` is the element with the ID `form-row`. Looking at your HTML that element is a div which contains 4 form inputs. This means that `formNum` is always going to start at 2. When `addForm` gets called this gets incremented to 3 and the input `id_form-TOTAL_FORMS` gets set to 4. You then submit this form and Django returns it back to you with errors.

To fix this you should add a class to the form row div and use that to count the forms:

```
<div id="form-row" class="row mt-0 no-gutters form-row">
```

And for counting the forms:

```
let formNum = document.querySelectorAll(".form-row").length - 1
```